# MicronautTest annotation skips test with DescribeSpec

Tags: kotlin, micronaut, kotest, micronaut-test

I'm trying to write a test using the @MicronautTest annotation in order to take advantage of the @Requires annotation so that I can run different tests depending on which MICRONAUT_ENVIRONMENTS variable(s) I set. I'm following what I see here: https://micronaut-projects.github.io/micronaut-test/latest/guide/#kotest

But my test is just being skipped. Here's the test:

```
@MicronautTest()
class SmokeTests: DescribeSpec ({
    describe("smoketests") {
        it("Should return 200 OK") {
            1 shouldBe 3
        }
    }
})
```

run with this command (This is located in a source set called smokeTest):

```
./gradlew smokeTest --info
```

Here's the log line I'm seeing:

```
com.sparkpost.sre.SmokeTests > smoketests SKIPPED
```

and here are my test dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    kaptTest("io.micronaut:micronaut-inject-java")
    testImplementation("io.kotest:kotest-runner-junit5-jvm:4.3.0")
    testImplementation("io.micronaut.test:micronaut-test-kotest:2.3.3")
    testImplementation( "io.mockk:mockk:1.10.5")
}
```

by the way, I *do* have this set:

```
tasks.withType<Test> {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: Does this test run if you simply run ./gradlew test ? I bet there's a problem with your source set definition.

Comment: hmmmm it 'runs' in that the correct class is run and that the test is actively skipped - as opposed to not seeing any information regarding the test at all. Based on that log line I posted, I know that micronaut is seeing and running the test, just skipping it.